# Specify path/name for Xcode 8.3.x command-line .ipa?

Tags: xcode, parameters, ipa, xcodebuild

With Xcode 8.2.1, if we use

xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath archivePath/OurApp.xcarchive -exportPath ipaPath/OurApp (other params left out for clarity)

the generated IPA will be in ipaPath/OurApp.ipa.

With Xcode 8.3.x if we use

xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath archivePath/OurApp.xcarchive -exportPath ipaPath/OurApp (other params left out for clarity)

the generated IPA will be in ipaPath/OurApp/XBuild.ipa.

Does anyone know of a way to force the previous behavior (I poured over the xcodebuild parameters and didn't see anything)...?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just try to find the generated file and move it to the desired location:

```
IPA_PATH="ipaPath/OurApp"
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath archivePath/OurApp.xcarchive -exportPath "$IPA_PATH"
mv "$(ls "$IPA_PATH/"*.ipa)" "${IPA_PATH}.ipa"
```

Comment: Yes, or work with the file in whatever location it ends up in (which is what I ended up doing). We have several scripts that use xcodebuild to make an ipa and I was hoping there was a command-line argument that would bring back the 8.2.1 behavior to make things easier though.